# Performance of FindGameObjectWithTag(Tag tag) Versus Using Public Variables for GameObjects in Unity

Tags: c#, performance, mobile, unity-game-engine

Basically, I am trying to optimize a game for Unity for mobile devices. Therefore, it is imperative to contain CPU usage. As this is a complex game, many of the scripts reference each other (and their GameObjects). Currently, I am using `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(Tag tag)` to reference other GameObjects, Components, and Scripts. I am also aware that this can be done with public variables by using the drag-and-drop in the editor. But as I know which GameObject will be dropped into each level, I found the first option to be simpler to use as the drag-and-drop led to errors many times and was tedious to use. However, that will not be a problem, and I feel performance of one or the other outweighs these fall backs. I was wondering if there was a difference in terms of performance for these two approaches, and which one would be better suited for a high performance, mobile, aspect.

Comment: Best to simply test it. I know that's mediocre "do it yourself!" advice, but you will get the most reliable and accurate information for your particular scenario if you benchmark your own code against your own (other) code.

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling Actually that's what I did. I initially had the drag and drop approach, but then since code led to be very messy with a lot of unnecessary (in my opinion anyway) public variables, I opted to use the FindGameObject option. However, I don't know if I'm just being paranoid or not, because there is a small change from one to the other. I was just curious if there was a "right" answer, if you will.

Comment: Benchmark. Time some loops with FindWithTag and your other method. See which is faster.

Comment: @Chris Yes, that's essentially what I did. I looked at the times, and the frame rates of the game with the two approaches. When looking at the profiler, I find that the FindWithTag option is better optimized but ironically, I think the FPS may be in favor of the drag and drop approach. This is why I am at a loss and was wondering if there was an "accepted" answer as mentioned in the last comment.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a private variable with the [SerializeField] tag?

Comment: @MikeB I found that the FindWithTag() approach to be slightly more efficient than the drag and drop. So I ended up choosing that over the public of [SerializeField] private option. However, any other public variable that wasn't being accessed by another script was given the [SerializeField] tag.

Comment: I have been seeing a bug where FindGameObjectWithTag() is not finding tagged prefabs. As a workaround I have to click any object in the hierarchy before debugging. This has led me to change a lot of references to drag and drop. I had thought that find with tag happened at runtime and drag and drop at compile time but it sounds like I need to rethink that

Comment: @MikeB Ah okay. That's interesting, as of now, I have yet to encounter any errors with FindGameObjectWithTag() in either compile time or runtime. In fact, I have had more problems with public variables in runtime that with the former option. I guess if I do encounter errors, I can always restructure the code for public variables.

Comment: If you do start getting an error where your objects are not being found try just clicking any item in the inspector and debug again and it works fine. It seems the bug happens anytime you click on a prefab then debug the game without first clicking the hierarchy. Thread on unity forums: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/serialization-prefab-bug.335877/#post-2183825

Comment: @MikeB Oh okay, I did not know that. Thanks so much! Hopefully I won't have to use that but it's great to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience your best bet is to create a public variable, if it isn't assigned when you need it, use your method of FindGameObjectWithTag or however you finding it before, store it in that public variable so you only have to do the lookup once.  As long as you don't do the FindGameObjectWithTag every frame the lookup hit shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Yea actually the reason for the frame drop in my case was the FindGameObjectWithTag inside of Update. I thought I had cached the variables but there were still some stray cases. Doing so has improved frame rate by nearly 30-40 fps. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`FindGameObjectWithTag()` has a complexity `O(n)` in the worst case scenario. You will not have performance issue if you have small amount of objects in your scene and small amount of objects searching for objects with tags.

Another approach is by serializing these objects in the script and using them. With this approach you decrease CPU usage and increase memory usage since no meta objects exist in the scene or not you allocate memory for them.

I suggest a third approach if it is possible for you. Search for Singleton pattern on Google and YouTube. It allows you to have a reference to that object if it's 1 all the time, without every time trying to find it with `FindGameObjectsWithTag()`... resulting in very small CPU and memory usage.